# Spring boot discord bot doesn' t respond

Tags: java, spring-boot, discord, bots, discord4j

I have created a discord bot using spring boot with discord4j dependency. The bot appears as online at the discord server, but doesn't respond to the command !todo which should have printed a to do list. The project compiles without any errors.

CONFIGURATION CLASS:

```
package com.example.demo;
import discord4j.core.DiscordClientBuilder;
import discord4j.core.GatewayDiscordClient;
import discord4j.core.event.domain.Event;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.List;

@Configuration
public class ConfigurationClass {



        @Value("${token}")
        private String token;
        @Bean
        public <T extends Event> GatewayDiscordClient gatewayDiscordClient(List<EventListener<T>> eventListeners) {
                GatewayDiscordClient client = DiscordClientBuilder.create(token)
                        .build()
                        .login()
                        .block();

                for (EventListener<T> listener : eventListeners) {
                        client.on(listener.getEventType())
                                .flatMap(listener::execute)
                                .onErrorResume(listener::handleError)
                                .subscribe();

                }

                return client;
        }


}
```

MESSAGE CREATED CLASS:

```
import com.austinv11.servicer.Service;
import discord4j.core.event.domain.message.MessageCreateEvent;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Service
public class MessageCreateListener extends MessageListener implements EventListener<MessageCreateEvent> {

    @Override
    public Class<MessageCreateEvent> getEventType() {
        return MessageCreateEvent.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> execute(MessageCreateEvent event) {
        return processCommand(event.getMessage());
    }
}
```

MESSAGE LISTENER CLASS:

```
package com.example.demo;

import discord4j.core.object.entity.Message;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public abstract class MessageListener {

    public Mono<Void> processCommand(Message eventMessage) {
        return Mono.just(eventMessage)
                .filter(message -> message.getAuthor().map(user -> !user.isBot()).orElse(false))
                .filter(message -> message.getContent().equalsIgnoreCase("!todo"))
                .flatMap(Message::getChannel)
                .flatMap(channel -> channel.createMessage("Things to do today:\n - write a bot\n - eat lunch\n - play a game"))
                .then();
    }
}
```

EVENT LISTENER INTERFACE :

```
package com.example.demo;

import discord4j.core.event.domain.Event;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;



public interface EventListener<T extends Event> {

    Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventListener.class);

    Class<T> getEventType();
    Mono<Void> execute(T event);

    default Mono<Void> handleError(Throwable error) {
        LOG.error("Unable to process " + getEventType().getSimpleName(), error);
        return Mono.empty();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `com.austinv11.servicer.Service` instead of `org.springframework.stereotype.Service` so `MessageCreateListener` will not be picked up by classpath scanning.

Comment: thanks a lot, that was the problem